# How to extract only the first instance of a number of lines between two strings in bash?

Tags: shell, awk, sed

My file is:

```
abc
123
xyz
abc
675
xyz
```

And I want to extract:

```
abc
123
xyz
```

(123 could be anything, the point is I want the first occurrence)

I tried using this:

```
sed -n '/abc/,/xyz/p' filename
```

but this is giving me all the instances. How could I get just the first one?

Comment: Don't use a range expression (`/start/,/end/`) as they just make trivial tasks very slightly briefer than using a flag and then need a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions when your requirements change in the slightest. Just use a flag (which means you can't use sed - oh well) indicate when you're in the block started by your first condition being true.

Comment: What is the expected output if there are no lines matching `xyz` following the line matching `abc` ?

Comment: What's the expected output if `abc` occurs twice before the first `xyz`?

Comment: Interesting questions. I should have mentioned it myself. 
1. There is no possibility of abc occurring twice before xyz. A maven check style plugin ensure that
2. If no lines match, no out is "expected", I'll make do with whatever I get, as long as it's definitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '/abc/{found=1} found; /xyz/ && found{exit}'  Input_file
```

OR as per Ed sir's comment for better efficiency try following.

```
awk '/abc/{found=1} found{print; if (/xyz/) exit}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '               ##Starting awk program from here.
/abc/{              ##checking condition if a line has abc in it then do following.
  found=1           ##Setting found here.
}
found;              ##Checking condition if found is SET then print that line.
/xyz/ && found{     ##Checking if xyz found in line and found is SET then do following.
  exit              ##exit program from here.
}
'  Input_file       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind Perl:

```
perl -ne 'm?abc?..m?xyz? and print' file
```

will print only the first block that matches. The delimiter for the matches must be the `?` character.

Comment: Does that exit after the first block is found or will it keep going reading all the lines after it? I honestly dont know as I'm not familiar with perl syntax and and how the various options affect what the script means/does.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, the 'm?PATTERN?..m?PATTERN?' stops matching after the first block. This once-only matching is described in more detail in [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.32.0/perlop.html#Range-Operators).

Comment: But it still *reads* the rest of the file, doesn't it? Just doesn't print?

Comment: @PaulHodges Yes, it still _reads_ the file. The `range` (...) operator becomes true on a match with the first operand and remains true until the second operand is true. Using `?` as the match delimiter limits the action to a once-only match unless a `reset` operator is used (as for processing a new file when an EOF on the first file is detected. Saying `...and print` is short for 'if (...) {print}`.

Comment: I'd just rather see it abort reading past the point where we know we're done. Nit-picky. :)

Comment: @PaulHodges There's more to using the `range` operator than shown in my example. The one-liner with one input file could be written to stop reading upon finding the end of block by testing for the terminal condition twice as others have noted. YMMV and TMTOWTDI

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` you can do:

```sh
sed -n '/abc/,/xyz/p; /xyz/q' filename
```

`q` will quit after the "xyz" pattern is reached.

Comment: In a file with "xyz" appears before "abc", this might result into something you don't want.

Comment: @kvantour But that's not the example provided by the OP.

Comment: @Todd Yes, but we like foolproof answers better in shell related tags

Comment: There are 3 cases the OP didn't address - 1) `xyz` before the first `abc`, 2) no `xyz` after the `abc`, and 3) 2 `abc`s before the first `xyz`. We can debate how we think the OP would want 2 and 3 handled but there's no question how `1` should be handled (ignore it) and it's trivial to handle so a reasonable answer would simply do so.

Comment: You could use `sed '/abc/,$! d ; /xyz/ q' input` to avoid the duplicate pattern and deal with `xyz` before `abc`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I believe OP can take the answer and improve it however they wish.

Answer (score 1):

### Match the Terminal Condition Twice

Regardless of the language, the most common technique for line-oriented processing is to print lines within a given range and then *use a second command* to exit the loop when your terminal condition is reached. This will be true for common patterns in sed, awk, ruby, and perl, although there are certainly other techniques that can be performed using multi-line matches (not supported in sed without using the hold space). For example, you might use a non-greedy, multi-line regular expression pattern such as `/^abc\n.*?\nxyz$/m`.

To illustrate the line-oriented approach you want a little more verbosely, consider this Ruby one-liner where `$_` holds the current input line. From the shell:

```
$ ruby -ne 'puts $_ if /^abc$/ .. /^xyz$/; exit if /^xyz/' filename 
abc
123
xyz
```

The equivalent in sed is:

```
$ sed -n '/^abc$/,/^xyz$/p; /^xyz$/q' filename
abc
123
xyz
```

All you were missing was a quit or exit command attached to the *second* match against the *first* instance of `xyz`.

Comment: Duplicate code such as specifying the same condition twice is usually (always?) a bad idea and idk what the ruby code does but the sed code would print nothing and exit if the first `xyz` appeared before the first `abc` in the input.

Comment: @EdMorton No. Sequenced instructions are the basic building blocks of any program. While some language features (e.g. the sed hold space, Perl/Ruby flip-flop operators, or multiline matches in supported regular expression enginers) may arguably allow you to avoid the need for a separate pattern match as opposed to backtracking, you aren't really avoiding a second instruction in any approach I can currently conceive. If you'd like to prove me wrong, please contribute your own answer for consideration.

Comment: idk what part of my comment you're saying `No` too but wrt what I'd do: since he was close I just commented on [@RavinderSingh13's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63073005/1745001) so he included my suggestion in his but it's just `awk '/abc/{f=1} f{print; if (/xyz/) exit}'`.

Comment: @EdMorton Count your conditions. You're just trading a pattern match for a variable test. You now have three commands/statements rather than two.

Comment: I don't care about how many conditions are present in the code as that's completely irrelevant. In addition to providing the expected output for the posted sample input and reasonably predictable other input I care about not having duplicate code (so I don't have to change 2 places in my code when my start or end regexp changes) and where in the code the conditions are tested (so I'm only performing a test when necessary) and exiting as soon as the first/only possible matching block is printed.

Comment: @EdMorton If you think your example is somehow more DRY, you're entitled to that viewpoint, although the value of DRY vs. DAMP in a one-liner is dubious at best. My examples work with the OP's example input and expected output, and if you don't like the way I explained the underlying approach that's up to you. I prefer to optimize for clarity and specificity; if you'd like to optimize for something else, that's fine too. [TIMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it).

Comment: Producing the expected output for a given sample input set is the starting point to identifying a solution, not the end point. Duplicate code is bad. Needlessly inefficient code is bad. Code that will clearly, obviously, and unnecessarily fail given a minor, predictable change to the input is bad. That's not just my viewpoint, it's programming fundamentals. I guess we'll just have to agree to disagree on how important they are.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been well and sufficiently answered and hashed out by better minds than me, but

1. since you explicitly used `sed`, and
2. for some variety of approach that handles the requested conditions...

```
sed -n '/abc/,/xyz/{ p; /xyz/q; }' filename
```

- This only looks at the range in question, so won't print or quit on `xyz` with no opening `abc` ahead of it
- it prints all the records in the range
- it *exits* on the first `xyz` it sees AFTER an `abc`, so will dependably exit
- if the end doesn't have an `xyz` it will just print to EOF.

You might refine the pattern if you want to make sure of exact matching, such as

```
sed -n '/^abc$/,/^xyz$/{ p; /^xyz$/q; }' filename
```

This prevents near-matches from confusing the logic, but is (intentionally) unforgiving of botched sentinel strings.

Comment: For non-GNU sed, replace the semicolons with newlines.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed '/abc/!d;:a;n;/xyz/!ba;q' file
```

If it is not a line containing `abc` delete it.

Otherwise, print it and fetch the next.

If that line is not `xyz`, repeat.

Otherwise, quit.

N.B. The option `-n` is not set and so the last line will be printed before termination.

This will print until the end of the file or the string `xyz` is encountered.

If `xyz` must be present, use:

```
sed -n '/abc/!d;:a;N;/xyz/!ba;p;q' file
```